# Flutter Firestore and StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm trying to build a google newsfeed like structure for my flutter app. There is no error in the design part. I tried with some dummy data and the widget build correctly. When I'm trying to convert firestore data into widget, the widget won't build and nothing in the screen. Below is StreamBuilder code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
        color: Colors.green[50],
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.04,
              ),
              Container(
                height: height * 0.12,
                width: width * 0.90,
                color: Colors.green[50],
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.10),
                        child: Text('UPCOMING EVENTS',
                            style: GoogleFonts.tenaliRamakrishna(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Events').snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
                  }
                  return ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents
                        .map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      return eventCard(
                          imageUrl: document['ImageUrl'],
                          title: document['Title'],
                          description: document['Description'],
                          venue: document['Venue'],
                          date: document['Date'],
                          time: document['Time']);
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

my widget code is

```
Widget eventCard(
      {String imageUrl,
      String title,
      String description,
      String venue,
      String date,
      String time}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: null,
        child: Container(
          height: height * 0.50,
          width: width * 0.90,
          decoration:
              kEventsPage.copyWith(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  child: Image.network(
                    imageUrl,
                    width: width * 90,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                        ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                      if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                      return Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                              ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                  loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                              : null,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                flex: 6,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          title,
                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          description,
                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                          child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Venue: ',
                                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                              ),
                              Text(venue)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Date: ',
                                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                              ),
                              Text(date)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Time: ',
                                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                              ),
                              Text(time)
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And the error is

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9553): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 9553): _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#21f5c):
I/flutter ( 9553): The getter 'documents' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9553): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 9553): Tried calling: documents
I/flutter ( 9553):
I/flutter ( 9553): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 9553):   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
I/flutter ( 9553):   file:///D:/Praveen/Flutter/FlutterApps/employee_tracking/lib/screens/Events.dart:169:15
I/flutter ( 9553): 
I/flutter ( 9553): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9553): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #1      _EventsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:employeetracking/screens/Events.dart:176:45)
I/flutter ( 9553): #2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:509:81)
I/flutter ( 9553): #3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:127:48)
I/flutter ( 9553): #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
I/flutter ( 9553): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
I/flutter ( 9553): #6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
I/flutter ( 9553): #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:11)
I/flutter ( 9553): #10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
I/flutter ( 9553): #12     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5947:32)
I/flutter ( 9553): ...     Normal element mounting (111 frames)
I/flutter ( 9553): #123    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
I/flutter ( 9553): #124    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3211:20)
I/flutter ( 9553): #125    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
I/flutter ( 9553): #126    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
I/flutter ( 9553): #127    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #128    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33)
I/flutter ( 9553): #129    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:20)
I/flutter ( 9553): #130    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #131    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter ( 9553): #132    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter ( 9553): #133    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter ( 9553): #137    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter ( 9553): #138    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter ( 9553): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 9553): 
I/flutter ( 9553): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/libEGL  ( 9553): EGLNativeWindowType 0x78761c2010 disconnect failed
I/SurfaceView( 9553): delay destroy surface control
E/SurfaceView( 9553): surfacePositionLost_uiRtSync  mSurfaceControl = null
W/libEGL  ( 9553): EGLNativeWindowType 0x78760c5010 disconnect failed
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#48731 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#48731 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#fd3bc relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#0133e relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#5ee9f relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#4cd88 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#35642 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#54fe5 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#15475 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#66748 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE  
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#01ac9 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#01ac9 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 9553): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#01ac9 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
W/FlutterJNI( 9553): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: lyokone/locationstream. Response ID: 0
W/FlutterJNI( 9553): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: lyokone/locationstream. Response ID: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason. It's because using `ListView` inside the `Column` widget. `Column` expands to the maximum size in main axis direction (vertical axis), and so does the `ListView`

### Solution:

Use either `Flexible` or `Expanded` if you want to allow `ListView` to take up entire left space in `Column`.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(...),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to try.

1) Replace

```dart
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
 }
```

with:

```dart
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
}
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return Center(child: Text('No data'),);
}
```

This will give the builder the time to fetch the data.

2) If you see `No data`, then go to Firebase console > Database > firestore  and check if there is a collection called `Events` at the root of the database. Check the capitalization, check if there are not extra invisible space. 
If this exists, click and Check if there are data in there

Comment: Yeah tried now, but still nothing on the screen except "Upcoming Events"

Comment: Data is there and if I print data inside builder method of StreamBuilder, it prints the data in terminal.